# Convert object to integer without losing the sense

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with different type of digits. I want to convert them to more clear digits. First I tried float then int. First one, for example turns out 2 but suppose to be 2607.

Hope someone can help. Regards

```py
x = ["2.6069999999999998","899.0", "1.974", "1.2309999999999999","882.0","839.0","525.0"]

xx = pd.DataFrame(x)

xx
```

Output:

```
    0
0   2.6069999999999998
1   899.0
2   1.974
3   1.2309999999999999
4   882.0
5   839.0
6   525.0
```

Expected Output:

```
    0
0   2607
1   899
2   1974
3   1231
4   882
5   839
6   525
```

Comment: How do you define _more meaningful_, i.e. why `2607` is more meaningful than `2.607` for example? Then show what have you tried so far.

Comment: That's right. So let's say more clear. So far I tried xx= xx.astype(float) then result is  
 '2.607'
 '899.000'
 '1.974'
 '1.231' '882.000'
'839.000'
 '525.000'  but I cannot convert them as expected. Thanks

Comment: Read again my question - How do you define more meaningful, i.e. why 2607 is more meaningful than 2.607 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
x = ["2.6069999999999998","899.0", "1.974", "1.2309999999999999","882.0","839.0","525.0"]
xx = []

for y in x:
    y = float(y)
    while y != round(y):
        y *= 10
        y = round(y , 3)
    xx.append(int(y))

print(xx)
```

output:

```
[2607, 899, 1974, 1231, 882, 839, 525]
```

very ugly tho